# How to enable push to talk for Skype for Business

Tags: skype-for-business

Is there a way to enable push to talk for Skype for Business? Some guides mention enabling it in "Advanced options" -> "hotkeys", but I cannot find advanced options or hotkeys under settings.

Comment: In the Mac Skype version 7.59 (since 5.0) DURING a call you can press Command-Option-Control-Up_Arrow to start push to talk. After than you must **hold** this conversation to talk. Muting/Unmuting cancel this. Has anyone tried this in Skype for Business? I'm unable to try it.

Answer (score 5):

"Push to talk" is currently only available in "Skype". "Skype for Business" is currently lacking this feature. You can however press *"Windows logo key"+F4* to toggle mute on/off. It's a global hotkey, so you don't need to have the window focused. When you mute the mic you will hear a *diu* sound and the mic icon will also change into [muted mic icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oohle.png). When you unmute there's no sound, but the mic icon will change back to into [mic open icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c5Hp.png).

Answer (score 4):

At time of writing this, Skype for Business does not have a native push to talk feature.

There is a [feature request](http://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/10836999-push-to-talk-option-and-keymapping-for-skype-for-b) for this here.